# I have a few questions

Tags: getorgchart

All of these questions pertain to GetOrgChart

1. Is there a way to embed a clickable link into one of the org boxes?
2. Can I mix shapes (some rectangles, some squares, etc.)
3. Is there any upper limit on the number of org chart nodes?

I'm not actually using this for an org chart. I am using it to display other hierarchical data.

Thanks
John

Answer (score 0):

here is an example how to embed a clickable link into one of the org boxes

```js
    $("#people").getOrgChart({ 
        renderBoxContentEvent: function( sender, args ) {
            if (args.id == 1){
                args.boxContentElements.push('<a xlink:href="http://www.GetOrgChart.com/"><text fill="#ffffff" width="330" x="10" y="100">go to www.getorgchart.com</text></a>');
                
            }
        },
        dataSource: [
            { id: 1, parentId: null, Name: "Amber McKenzie", Title: "CEO", Address: "MyAddress"},
            { id: 2, parentId: 1, Name: "Ava Field", Title: "CTO", Phone: "+359 888 888 888", Image: "http://www.getorgchart.com/GetOrgChart/getorgchart-demos/images/f-6.jpg"},
            { id: 3, parentId: 1, Name: "Evie Johnson", Title: "CFO", Car: "BMW"}]
    });
```

```css
html, body {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
#people {width: 100%;height: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getorgchart.com/GetOrgChart/getorgchart/getorgchart.js"></script>
<link href="http://getorgchart.com/GetOrgChart/getorgchart/getorgchart.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="people"></div>
```

Here is an example of mixed shapes
http://www.getorgchart.com/Demos/Mixed-Shapes

Regarding your last question, the limit depend of your browser